# How to prevent Action on handleKeyCommand in Draft Js

Tags: reactjs

I am not able to do it by `error.preventDefault()`. In the case below I want to kill the event on press of enter it is killing the event but giving error.

- Code

  ```
   handleKeyCommand(command) {
       if (command === 'split-block')
           command.event.preventDefault();
       }
       const { editorState } = this.state;
       const newState = RichUtils.handleKeyCommand(editorState, command);

       if (newState) {
           this.onChange(newState);
           return true;
       } 

       return false;
   }
  ```
- Error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined

Comment: I think you have to use `command.preventDefault();` instead of  `command.event.preventDefault();` this I hope it will be work.
You have to pass the data like this `(e) => handleKeyCommand(e)` that you have to use

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking to use this https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-editor/#keybindingfn. The `keyBindingFn` has a keyboard event that you can call `preventDefault` and other event functions. The function allows you to return a command that you can then handle in the `handleKeyCommand` function. Just make sure to `return getDefaultKeyBinding(event)` by default if you want to keep the default key bindings.